# OSM Overlapping Polygon symbolism editing .xml

Tags: geoserver, sld, overlapping-features

Looking to show both administrative boundaries of counties as states.  There seems to be something that is showing counties and not states when both are showing for a certain zoom level.  attached is my .xml to show how I am styling.

```
 <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
      <se:Rule>
        <se:Name>Boundary</se:Name>
        <se:Description>
          <se:Title>Counties etc.</se:Title>
        </se:Description>
        <ogc:Filter>
          <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLike wildCard="*" singleChar="#" escapeChar="!">
              <ogc:PropertyName>boundary</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>administrative</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsLike>
            <ogc:PropertyIsLike wildCard="*" singleChar="#" escapeChar="!">
              <ogc:PropertyName>admin_level</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>6</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsLike>
          </ogc:And>
        </ogc:Filter>
        <se:MinScaleDenominator>0</se:MinScaleDenominator>
        <se:MaxScaleDenominator>3000000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
        <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
          <se:Fill>
            <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#f2f2f2</se:SvgParameter>
            <se:SvgParameter name="fill-opacity">0.1</se:SvgParameter>
          </se:Fill>
          <se:Stroke>
            <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#8f8f8f</se:SvgParameter>
            <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
            <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
            <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-dasharray">2</se:SvgParameter>
          </se:Stroke>
        </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        <se:TextSymbolizer>
          <se:Label>
            <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
          </se:Label>
          <se:Font>
            <se:SvgParameter name="font-size">10</se:SvgParameter>
            <se:SvgParameter name="font-family">Nimbus Sans L Regular</se:SvgParameter>
          </se:Font>
          <se:LabelPlacement>
             <se:PointPlacement>
             <se:AnchorPoint>
               <se:AnchorPointX>0.5</se:AnchorPointX>
               <se:AnchorPointY>0.5</se:AnchorPointY>
             </se:AnchorPoint>
           </se:PointPlacement>
          </se:LabelPlacement>
          <se:Halo>
            <se:Radius>
              <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
            </se:Radius>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#2d2d2d</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
          </se:Halo>
          <se:Fill>
            <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#f2f2f2</se:SvgParameter>
          </se:Fill>
          <se:VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">50</se:VendorOption>
          <se:VendorOption name="labelAllGroup">TRUE</se:VendorOption>
          <se:VendorOption name="removeOverlaps">TRUE</se:VendorOption>
          <se:VendorOption name="autoWrap">40</se:VendorOption>
          <se:VendorOption name="group">TRUE</se:VendorOption>
        </se:TextSymbolizer>
      </se:Rule>
  </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
  <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
      <se:Rule>
        <se:Name>Boundary</se:Name>
        <se:Description>
          <se:Title>States</se:Title>
        </se:Description>
        <ogc:Filter>
          <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLike wildCard="*" singleChar="#" escapeChar="!">
              <ogc:PropertyName>boundary</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>administrative</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsLike>
            <ogc:PropertyIsLike wildCard="*" singleChar="#" escapeChar="!">
              <ogc:PropertyName>admin_level</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>5</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsLike>
          </ogc:And>
        </ogc:Filter>
        <se:MinScaleDenominator>2000000</se:MinScaleDenominator>
        <se:MaxScaleDenominator>100000000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
        <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
          <se:Fill>
            <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#f2f2f2</se:SvgParameter>
            <se:SvgParameter name="fill-opacity">0.1</se:SvgParameter>
          </se:Fill>
          <se:Stroke>
            <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#262626</se:SvgParameter>
            <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">2</se:SvgParameter>
            <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
          </se:Stroke>
        </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        <se:TextSymbolizer>
          <se:Label>
            <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
          </se:Label>
          <se:Font>
            <se:SvgParameter name="font-size">14</se:SvgParameter>
            <se:SvgParameter name="font-family">Nimbus Sans L Regular</se:SvgParameter>
          </se:Font>
          <se:LabelPlacement>
             <se:PointPlacement>
             <se:AnchorPoint>
               <se:AnchorPointX>0.5</se:AnchorPointX>
               <se:AnchorPointY>0.5</se:AnchorPointY>
             </se:AnchorPoint>
           </se:PointPlacement>
          </se:LabelPlacement>
          <se:Halo>
            <se:Radius>
              <ogc:Literal>1.75</ogc:Literal>
            </se:Radius>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#2d2d2d</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
          </se:Halo>
          <se:Fill>
            <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#f2f2f2</se:SvgParameter>
          </se:Fill>
          <se:VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">50</se:VendorOption>
          <se:VendorOption name="labelAllGroup">TRUE</se:VendorOption>
          <se:VendorOption name="removeOverlaps">TRUE</se:VendorOption>
          <se:VendorOption name="autoWrap">40</se:VendorOption>
          <se:VendorOption name="group">TRUE</se:VendorOption>
        </se:TextSymbolizer>
      </se:Rule>
  </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
```

Here is an image of the zoom level that is only showing the counties.

[image]

Comment: what is the scale denominator of that image? what software are you using?

Comment: I am editing OSM Data sld style sheets for a WMS layer that will be in QGIS.  It seems to me I am just missing some sort of overlapping variable

Comment: what WMS software are you using?

Comment: i am producing it and hosting it in Geoserver

Comment: and you are sure the scale is between 2,000,000 and 3,000,000?

Comment: the issues is that the two polygons State and County are to be showing at the same time and for some reason, County overlaps State?  the scale is correct, the gap between 2,000,000 and 3,000,000 is when both layers should be showing.  Thank you for all your help on this matter!